# Need to delay navigateToURL Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a MovieClip (called "Chats") which plays when it is clicked but then I need it to navigateToURL when it has finished playing. This is as close as I have got but it doesn't work:

```
var chatTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
chats.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,startTimer);
function startTimer(event:MouseEvent):void {

chats.gotoAndPlay(2);
chats.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,urlAction);
function urlAction(){
chatTimer.stop();
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
}
```

Hope you can help!
Steph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to call navigateToURL once a movieclip has reached the final frame in its timeline. This is a lot easier if you use the totalFrames and currentFrame properties, like so:

```
chats.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, begin);

/**
 * Begins the playing of chats
 */
function begin(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // only runs if the movieclip is on frame 1
    // (can't click it multiple times)
    if(chats.currentFrame == 1)
    {
    chats.gotoAndPlay(2);
    chats.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handleChats);
   }
}

function _handleChats(e:Event):void
{
   var m:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);

   if(m.currentFrame == m.totalFrames)
   {
       m.stop();

       var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/");
       navigateToURL(req, "_blank");

       m.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handleChats);
   }
}
```

Hope this is what you were after!

Comment: Thanks Marty, I get an error message saying: "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ." about var req:URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/"); any ideas?

Comment: Does it say which type was not found? If you're placing this code into an external file (Class) then you will need to import the following: flash.display.MovieClip, flash.net.URLRequest, flash.net.navigateToURL, flash.events.Event.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit late for me. Missed a vital part! Try the amended code above :)

Comment: I've imported them and used the code you gave me but it still has a problem with the var req:URLRequest("stackoverflow.com"); line

Comment: I forgot to add new URLRequest() and just had req:URLRequest(""); Works perfectly for me!

Comment: That works well thanks :) the only thing i need to do now is make it happen when the movie clip is clicked on...?

Comment: No problems. Thanks for asking a question that was easy and didn't need deciphering :)